# Proper way to 301 redirect using Nginx

Tags: php, http, redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I'm using Nginx as a webserver. I need to 301 redirect url in following pattern

```
adomain.com/detail.php?name=eC-F_VZ2T1c
```

into

```
adomain.com/watch?v=eC-F_VZ2T1c
```

Tried this snippet

```
location /detail.php {
    if ($arg_name) {
        return 301 http://adomain.com/watch?v=$arg_name;
    }
}
```

No success!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have better luck with `rewrite` - try replacing your return line with the following:

```
rewrite ^ http://adomain.com/watch?v=$arg_name permanent;
```

The `permanent` flag indicates a permanent 301 redirect.

As per documentation found at:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: `invalid parameter "permament"`

Comment: hmm, what version and installation package of nginx are you using?

Comment: I think that they might be using mgimx instead